# Refresh gallery after delete image from the external storage

Tags: android

My problem is that i'm deleting the images from the external storage and a black place holder is still there referring to deleted image location.

Here is code please help me to to get it out.

Thanks in advance.

```
 String canonicalPath;
        try {
            canonicalPath = file.getCanonicalPath();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            canonicalPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
        }
        final Uri uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
        final int result = contentResolver.delete(uri,
                MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA + "=?", new String[]{canonicalPath});
        if (result == 0) {
            final String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
            if (!absolutePath.equals(canonicalPath)) {
                contentResolver.delete(uri,
                        MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA + "=?", new String[]{absolutePath});
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've always used this function for my music app, but should work for gallery as well.
This first finds the `_id` of the desidered entry, then it builds the correct uri to submit to the deletion query.

```
public void deleteFromMediaStore(String pathToDelete, Context context) {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    if (contentResolver != null) {
        Cursor matchingIndex = contentResolver.query(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[]{"_id", "_data"}, "_data=?", new String[]{pathToDelete}, null);

        if(matchingIndex != null && matchingIndex.getCount() > 0) {
            matchingIndex.moveToFirst();
            while (!matchingIndex.isAfterLast()) {
                context.getContentResolver().delete(ContentUris.withAppendedId(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, (long) matchingIndex.getInt(matchingIndex.getColumnIndex("_id"))), null, null);
                matchingIndex.moveToNext();
            }
            matchingIndex.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working i'm sending below path as a string in this method
"/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Sticker/stricker1.jpg"
Is it correct ?
this image is deleted from this location.
After delete this image i'm calling deleteFromMediaStore() this method?

Comment: @Rinkukataria there might be a problem with your device. The above code is in a production app and it' working across thousands of devices.

Comment: Yes i understand. matchingIndex.getCount()  is returning me 0.
please tell me what to send in path i'm sending  /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Sticker/stricker1.jpg",
File:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Sticker/stricker1.jpg"
i have tried with both these paths but it is not working.can you please explain me.

Answer (score 0):

you can send a broadcast

```
Intent intent =
      new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

or if you want callback

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(
      getApplicationContext(),
      new String[]{file.getAbsolutePath()},
      null,
      new OnScanCompletedListener() {
         @Override
         public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {

         }
      });
```